# SQL Reporting 2008 and Excel as Data Source

Tags: sql, excel, ssrs-2008

I am working on a project were we need to develop SQL Reports based on some excel files.

I was able to create the ODBC for the Excel file and I was able to connect to it successfully using the Report Services.

My question is:

How can I used paramaters in the query ? When I try to use @CIF or @StartDate I get all kinds of errors and I don't know how to use parameters with SQL query for Excel.

Sample:

```
SELECT * FROM [Loans$] Where [CIF] = @CIF
```

Can anyone tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

If you are successfully extracting information without trying to filter at the query level, as a workaround you can add the filtering at the DataSet level, something like:

[image]

This will extract data from the DataSet *then* apply any filter, not try to do it at the same time.

It's might not be addressing your root cause, but will hopefully get you up and running in the meantime.

Since you don't actually list the errors you're getting, it's hard to offer more specific advice.